# Simple loop in NASM from C

Tags: c, loops, assembly, x86, nasm

Im trying to work with nasm from C and just having a hard time with the basics of nasm. Im trying to convert a simple while loop like this

```
while(j < k)
{k = k + 1;
 j = j + 2;
 count = count + 1;
}
```

I know that it will look something like

```
Loopee:

????
add dword [k], 1
add dword [j], 2
add dword [count], 1
```

but I'm not sure how to structure the while loop where it only loops until j is no longer less than k.

Comment: Have you seen this link? [assembly to compare two numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123396/assembly-to-compare-two-numbers)

Comment: Write it in C first, then use your compiler to generate asm (e.g. `gcc -S ...`), then use the generated asm as a template for your own code.

Comment: In order to write assembly code, you must first understand the processor instruction set. Here's a **[link](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html)** to the documentation. It's only 3400 pages, so you should be able to finish reading it by tomorrow :)

Answer (score 2):

A while loop is just like an IF statement, except that at the bottom of the body you unconditionally jump back to the IF (the start of the loop).