# Compare two variables in assembly

Tags: assembly

What is the assembly syntax to compare if 2 variable are equal?

I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123396/assembly-to-compare-two-numbers)

but it didn't work.

Comment: what assembly? what have you tried? what does it produce?

Answer (score 0):

In `x86` assembly the corresponding instruction is `CMPSD`. In the `Intel Instruction manual` it is described as

> OpCode bytes: A7 --- instruction: CMPSD --- Encoding:NP --- 64-bit:Valid --- 32-bit:Valid
>
> - For legacy mode, compare dword at address
>                        DS:(E)SI with dword at address ES:(E)DI;
> - For
>                       64-bit mode compare dword at address (R|E)SI
>                      with dword at address (R|E)DI. The status flags
>                     are set accordingly.

`CMPSD` compares two memory operands and sets the status flags in `EFLAGS` accordingly for consumption of `Jcc/CMOVcc/...`.

So, for comparing two DWORD/4-byte variables you setup ESI and EDI like this

```
lea esi, var1     ; ESI = address of var1 
lea edi, var2     ; EDI = address of var2
cmpsd             ; compare them
Jcc...            ; use (E)FLAGS
```

For other variable sizes like 1,2,4,8 bytes use CMPS(B,W,D,Q) respectively.